# EF Core - IdentityUser mapping in two tables

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, identity, ef-core-5.0

I implemented Identity in my Identity Server project and I'm facing a problem trying to map IdentityUser class to my already existing DB configuration.

The main problem is that IdentityUser properties are split into two tables in my configuration (mainly password is in another table).

I tried to create my classes accordingly:

```cs
public partial class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public override int Id { get => base.Id; set => base.Id = value; }
    public override string Email { get => base.Email; set => base.Email = value; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public override string NormalizedUserName { get => base.NormalizedUserName; set => base.NormalizedUserName = value; }
    public override string UserName { get => base.UserName; set => base.UserName = value; }
}

public class UserMapping : User
{
    public override string PasswordHash { get => base.PasswordHash; set => base.PasswordHash = value; }
    public override int AccessFailedCount { get => base.AccessFailedCount; set => base.AccessFailedCount = value; }
    public override bool EmailConfirmed { get => base.EmailConfirmed; set => base.EmailConfirmed = value; }
}
```

I tried every configuration I could think of but couldn't manage to map IdentityUser properties like the PasswordHash property to another table.

My db context, as for now, is as follow :

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<UserMapping>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("myOtherTable");

    entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
    entity.Property(e => e.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("Password");
    entity.Property(e => e.AccessFailedCount).HasColumnName("PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess");
    entity.Property(e => e.EmailConfirmed).HasColumnName("IsConfirmed");

    entity.HasOne<User>()
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<User>(e => e.Id);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("User");

    entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("IdUser");
    entity.Property(e => e.UserName).HasColumnName("Username");
    entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasColumnName("UpperUsername");

    entity.HasKey(e => e.Id)
        .HasName("PK_dbo.User");
});
```

When querying with ef core, the properties that I tried to override in `UserMapping` class are linked to the `User` class except `AccessFailedCount` (I have no clue why)

```sql
SELECT [User].[IdUser], 
       [User].[Email], 
       [User].[IsConfirmed], 
       [User].[UpperUsername], 
       [User].[Password], 
       [User].[Telephone], 
       [User].[Username], 
       [UserMapping].[PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess], 
       [UserMapping].[ConfirmationToken], 
       [UserMapping].[CreateDate], 
       [UserMapping].[LastPasswordFailureDate], 
       [UserMapping].[PasswordChangedDate], 
       [UserMapping].[PasswordSalt], 
       [UserMapping].[PasswordVerificationToken], 
       [UserMapping].[PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate], 
FROM [User] AS [User]
LEFT JOIN [myOtherTable] AS [UserMapping] ON [User].[IdUser] = [UserMapping].[IdUser]
WHERE [User].[Email] = @__email_0
ORDER BY [User].[IdUser]
```

Is there any way to map it?

Hope I was clear enough, thank you for your help!

Comment: just a common mistake when following this process: In your dbcontext, onmodelcreating, do you have the `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)` called?

Comment: I do, first line of my OnModelCreating function !

Comment: I'm afraid the so called "entity splitting" is not yet supported (even EFC 5.0)

Comment: I thought so too but the property `AccessFailedCount` (`PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess` in sql db) is splitted ! What I don't understand is why the other properties aren't. My guess was missmatch type with db but I couldn't make it work so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually managed to do it !

The trick was to ignore the properties I wanted to override from the base classe before hand, like so :

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(c => c.AccessFailedCount)
                           .Ignore(c => c.PasswordHash)
                           .Ignore(c => c.EmailConfirmed)
```